# About an exact homotopy sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'll call the pair of the space and its subspace (A, B) contractible if there is a homotopy $\Phi^t: B \to A$ such that $\Phi^0$ is $\text{Id}_B$ and $\text{Im}$ $\Phi^1$  is a point. For example, the pair $(D^i,$ $\partial D^i)$ of the closed ball and its boundary is contractible.

The first part of my problem is quite simple: if the pair (A, B) is contractible, it's easy to show that in its long exact homotopy sequence $\pi_i(A) \to \pi_i(A, B)$ is monomorphism and $\pi_i(A, B) \to  \pi_{i-1}(B)$ is epimorphism.

But after that, I've to prove that $\pi_i(A, B) \simeq \pi_i(A) \oplus \pi_{i-1}(B)$. The key moment is that author uses $\oplus$ symbol here.

The case $i \geq 3$ isn't obvious for me. And it's my first question: why our sequence is splitting? Should we construst a splitting morphism $\pi_{i -1}(B) \to \pi_i(A, B)$?

If $i = 1$ problem is incorrect: $\pi_1(A, B)$ group isn't a group.

My second question is what can I do if $i = 2$? We don't know anything about commutativeness of $\pi_1(B)$ and $\pi_2(A, B)$. And it's easy to show an example where $
\pi_1(B)$ isn't commutative (and $\pi_2(A, B)$ also isn't commutative because there is an epimorphism from  $\pi_2(A, B)$ to $\pi_1(B)$). In this case, the symbol $\oplus$ is incorrect. So are both of cases $i = 1$ and $ i=2$ incorrect? Or in the second of them, I should change $\oplus$ to $\times$ and prove that $\pi_i(A, B) \simeq \pi_i(A) \times \pi_{i-1}(B)$? How to do that? I haven't any ideas...

Comment: The image of the monomorphism $\pi_2(A)\to\pi_2(A,B)$ is a normal subgroup (since the sequence is exact). And the quotient $\pi_2(A,B)/\pi_2(A)$ is isomorphic to $\pi_1(B)$. These two facts together are enough to prove that as a set $\pi_2(A,B)$ is the Cartesian product $\pi_2(A)\times\pi_1(B)$. It is unlikely that it is the direct product. It is possible that it is a semi-direct product though. How do you prove that it is the direct product for $i\geq 3$? You say it is obvious, but I don't see it.

Comment: Let's look at our exact homotopy sequence. All morphisms $\pi_n(B) \to \pi_n(A)$ are zeros (because the pair is contractible).
It follows from this fact that we have a short exact sequence $0 \to \pi_i(A) \to \pi_i(A, B) \to \pi_{i -1}(B) \to 0$. All groups here are abelian since $(i \geq 3)$. It means that $\pi_i(A, B) \simeq \pi_i(A) \oplus \pi_{i -1}(B)$.

Comment: No, it doesn't. For example consider the short exact sequence $0\to\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\to 0$. Your claim is true if $\pi_i(A,B)$ is finitely generated (which obviously doesn't have to hold). Or when the short exact sequence splits which might be but I'm not sure why. Note that if the sequence splits then it probably splits for $i=2$ as well producing semi-direct product (we need "semi" due to non-abelian).

Comment: @freakish Yes, you're right. I think that I must think about this problem for the longer time.

Comment: @freakish Can the splitting lemma help us?

Comment: Oops, finitely generated is not enough as $0\to\mathbb{Z}_2\to\mathbb{Z}_4\to\mathbb{Z}_2\to 0$ shows, sorry for the mistake. Yes, we have to use the splitting lemma somehow. But I'm not sure how to construct the "split" morphism $\pi_{i-1}(B)\to\pi_i(A,B)$.

Comment: @freakish I've fixed my question...

Comment: I was fixated on "right split" while actually we should probably look at "left split", i.e. a map $\pi_i(A,B)\to\pi_i(A)$. This looks easier (although I still can't figure out details). Note that "left split" produces direct product even in non-abelian case.

Comment: @freakish Can we do something like the following?

Let $\psi$ denote a map $S^n \to B$. We can think about $\psi$ as about a null-homotopic map $S^n \to A$. It's null-homotopic so there is a map $\Omega(\psi): D^{n + 1} \to A$ such that $\Omega(\psi)|_{S^n} \equiv \psi$. 

Now we can see that $\Omega$ is the splitting map $\pi_{i-1}(B) \to \pi_i(A, B)$. Isn't it?

Comment: @freakish Are there any mistakes in my proof?

Comment: Right, so this is a well defined map and I think even a homomorphism. All that remains is to show that it actually is a splitting of $\pi_i(A,B)\to\pi_{i-1}(B)$.

Comment: @freakish The image of the map $D^{n} \to A$ under the morphism $\pi_n(A, B) \to \pi_{n-1}(B)$ is the restriction of this map to $S^{n-1}$. Why we can't say that $\Omega$ a splitting map since $\Omega(\psi)|_{S^{i-1}} \equiv \psi$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've totally forgotten how $\pi_n(A,B)\to\pi_{n-1}(B)$ is defined. So yes, this will give you a right split and therefore $\pi_n(A,B)$ is a direct product for $n\geq 3$ and semi-direct product for $n=2$.

Comment: @freakish Have you actually proved that it's a semi-direct product?

Comment: Have a look at [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma) and read about splitting lemma for non-abelian groups. There's more info about it in the article on [semi-direct products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product).

Comment: @freakish Thank you very much for useful discussion! I was glad to talk to you.

Comment: No problem, I've enjoyed the discussion as well. I suggest you write the answer yourself because it was actually you who found the splitting.

Comment: @freakish The answer's written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at our exact homotopy sequence. All morphisms $\pi_n(B) \to \pi_n(A)$ are zeros (because the pair is contractible). It follows from this fact that we have a short exact sequence $0 \to \pi_i(A) \to \pi_i(A, B) \to \pi_{i-1}(B) \to 0$. 
Now there are two cases.

1. $i \geq 3$. All groups here are abelian so we can use the splitting lemma. Our goal is to construct a splitting morphism $\Omega: \pi_{i−1}(B) \to \pi_i(A, B)$. 
   We can do something like this: let $\psi$ denote a map $S^n \to B$. We can think about $\psi$ as about a null-homotopic map $S^n \to A$. It's null-homotopic so there is a map $\Omega(\psi): D^{n+1} \to A$ such that $\Omega(\psi)|_{S^n}\equiv \psi$. Now we can easily see that $\Omega$ is the splitting map. And my proposition about existence of isomorphism $\pi_i(A, B) \simeq \pi_i(A) \oplus \pi_{i-1}(B)$ follows from this fact.
2. $i = 2$. The morphism $\Omega$ which was described above is a correct splitting map also. So due to splitting lemma for non-abelian groups $\pi_2(A, B)$ is a semi-direct product of $\pi_2(A)$ and $\pi_1(B)$.

P.S. I would like to gratefully thank user @freakish for useful discussion.